# Bing index 0 of 265 URL's in our sitemap.xml

Tags: bing-webmaster-tools

I have submitted our sitemap.xml in Bing Webmaster Tools in the beginning of September. Nothing was indexed after more than a month, so I resubmitted the sitemap 2 days ago. The status is Success but still 0 URL's are submitted. This sitemap.xml works well for Google.
See screenshot:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that this is probably an error that related to the module which you used to set up the sitemap. https://github.com/wilr/silverstripe-googlesitemaps

I would suggest adding this as an issue to the GitHub page for more information?